# Installing BetterCap on Mac BigSur (adoptation from existing youtube tutorial)

Tags: macos

I find a tutorial to install BetterCap on Ubuntu Linux at
[You tube tube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isiWkYk2xas&t=24s)

Can some one do a favor of adopting them to Mac Big Sur ver 11.0
When I run them, it is not able to recognise Java Run time even though 3 instances are present.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
17.0.1 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 17.0.1" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1_1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_312 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 8" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+312/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_312 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Users/venkatanutalapati/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_312/Contents/Home
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1_1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

The detailed steps in the description are...

```
- sudo apt update
       
 - sudo apt install libpcap-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev
       
 -  wget https://github.com/bettercap/betterca...
       
 -  unzip bettercap_linux_amd64_v2.26.1.zip
       
 -  sudo mv -v bettercap /usr/bin
       
 -  rm -rf bettercap_linux_amd64_v2.26.1.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bettercap seems to have a homebrew formulae - just try to run `brew install bettercap` and it should install it for you. No need to get it directly from git and follow all of these steps

Comment: Supercool @LielFridman. It worked like a charm. Awesome!
Kudos!